# Unity - WPF MVVM Ligth - Interceptor

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, unity-container

I have some issue using an `interceptor` on Wpf  MVVM Light `Usercontrol`.

When i try to use an `interceptor` on a WPF `userControl` i am unable to use it as `window.Content`.
My application display the dynamics type of the `userControl` instead of display the xaml part.

without `interceptor` :
http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/984030821.jpg

with `interceptor` : 
http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/526552682.jpg

sample :

```
var container = new Container();
var view = container.Resolve<IAuthView>("auth");

var window = new Window();
window.Content = view;

window.ShowDialog();
```

Container :

```
// Working well.
this.RegisterType<IAuthView, AuthView>("auth", new InjectionConstructor(this.Resolve<IAuthViewModel>()));


// Not working.
this.AddNewExtension<Interception>();

this.RegisterType<IAuthView, AuthView>("auth", new InjectionConstructor(this.Resolve<IAuthViewModel>()), new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(), new InterceptionBehavior<LoggingInterceptionBehavior>());
```

nota : I think my `interceptor` is ok because of when i try with a non WPF `UserControl` it work well.
nota2 : the methods `WillExecute` and `GetRequiredInterfaces` are well called.

I search and search again on the web without result :(

Any idea ?

Comment: Could you try using a [VirtualMethodInterceptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466(v=pandp.30).aspx#sec11) instead?  The dynamic proxy it is creating from your interface is not likely derived from a wpf control class.  Also, you should not use this.Resolve() within an InjectionConstructor.  Use [ResolvedParameter<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee651476(v=pandp.30).aspx) instead.

Comment: thanks for the hint ;)
little move on my error : with  

`this.RegisterType<IAuthView, AuthView>("auth", new Interceptor<VirtualMethodInterceptor>(), new InterceptionBehavior<LoggingInterceptionBehavior>());` 
the uri was not found `/MainFrames;component/views/authview.xaml`